# Echo to file apparently needs double escaping backslash (\\\n) to write \n. Why?

Tags: bash, sh

As per the [graylog2 docs](http://www.graylog2.org/resources/documentation/sending/syslog), I need to add this line to my rsyslog.conf:

```
$template GRAYLOGRFC5424,"<%pri%>%protocol-version% %timestamp:::date-rfc3339% %HOSTNAME% %app-name% %procid% %msg% \n"
```

I'm doing it programmatically when I spin up a server, so the command I've got going currently is:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "\$template GRAYLOGRFC5424,\"<%pri%>%protocol-version% %timestamp:::date-rfc3339% %HOSTNAME% %app-name% %procid% %msg% \\\n\"" >> rsyslog.conf'
```

I'm escaping the dollar sign, both double quotes, and the backslash before the n. However, `\n` and `\\n` both write an actual newline to the file, but `\\\n` writes `\n` correctly. Why doesn't `\\n` work?

Comment: Even though tag `bash`, the behaviour is with `sh`. If you do `sudo bash -c ...`, you'll get different results.

Comment: ah well that fixes it. Still curious what's up with sh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to come from the builtin `echo` in `dash` (which is `sh` in Ubuntu by default), which seems to process its `\` arguments differently from other implementations (`/bin/echo` and the builtin `echo` in Bash):

```
$ sh -c "echo '\\n'" 


$ sh -c "/bin/echo '\\n'"
\n
$ bash -c "echo '\\n'"
\n
```

This is not surprising, as using `\` arguments in `echo` is non-standard:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/echo.html

> If the first operand is **-n**, or if any of the operands contain a backslash ( '\' ) character, the results are implementation-defined.

You should use `printf` instead of `echo`, like this:

```
printf '$template GRAYLOGRFC5424,"<%%pri%%>%%protocol-version%% %%timestamp:::date-rfc3339%% %%HOSTNAME%% %%app-name%% %%procid%% %%msg%% \\n"\n' | sudo tee -a rsyslog.conf
```

As a added bonus, using `sudo tee` to write to files as root instead of `sudo sh -c` + shell redirections makes the command cleaner, since the string is parsed only once (as an argument to `printf`) instead of twice (first as an argument to `sh -c` and then as an argument to `echo`).

Comment: It already works, I'm looking for explanations. Why is that the right tool for the job?

Comment: Sorry, I misread. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Using `\n` and friends with `echo` is non-standard? What reference do you have for such a statement?

Comment: @muru I don't very much like your tone but... http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/echo.html *"If the first operand is -n, or if any of the operands contain a backslash ( '\' ) character, the results are implementation-defined."*

Comment: The source is very easily obtainable, for anyone who honestly wants it (as opposed to arguing for the sake of arguing).